# After migrating to API Platform 3, some IRI resources are inconsistent

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

We recently migrated to API Platform 3.

We found an inconsistency in the identifiers of some API resources (@id)

When we perform a creation request on the Customer resource, the IRI identifier does not correspond to the resource.

Instead of containing `"@id": "/customers/xxxxxx"`
it contains `"@id": "/customers/xxxx/insurances"`.

However, the type key does contain the definition of the desired resource:
`"@type": "Customer"`